# Location of class member changes when class method is accessed from different places

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

I am having a problem of the location of a class member changes depending on when a function is run.

When the constructor is running, the location of a member is 0x008bc044. Then later  a member function is called and the location of the same member is still 0x008bc044. Even later on the member function is run again but the location of the same member changes to 0x008bc048. All other members of the class don't change there location.
I am not casting the class to another type.

This is causing a problem because the function is now reading random data and causing incorrect output.

I am using Visual Studio 2012, 11.0.60315.01 Update 2.

[Album of visual studio debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyYzg.jpg)

Comment: can you show us the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running a 32 bit system, have a a derived class and show the pointer of the base class and the pointer of the derived class. In addition you have a reinterpret or c-style cast.

Comment: Thanks, I found problem in a library that I was using which was casting my class to another type expecting that it only inherited from a type from that library.